# Change cursor to default in anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I have an **anchor tag** in which I removed the `href` attribute through JavaScript.
I had also used `setAttribute` to add `style="cursor:default;"`
But still the hand pointer is being displayed on hovering over the text.
What is that I am doing wrong here.

**HTML**

```
<li>
<a class="menu-item" href="www.google.com" > 
 <span>Link Text</span>
</a>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function removeLink()
{
menuItem.removeAttribute("href");
menuItem.setAttribute("style","cursor:default;");
}
```

After page load html becomes like this

```
<li>
<a class="menu-item" style="cursor:default;" > 
 <span>Link Text</span>
</a>
</li>
```

When the page is rendered these changes are visible in the code, But still i get the Hand pointer on hovering over the link

I have already tried using menuItem.style.cursor="default";
And also tried to set it through css

**CSS**

```
.class a:hover{
cursor:default;}
```

Comment: try
`menuItem.style.cursor='default'`

Comment: show your HTML code also

Comment: @Mike... hi i have added my HTML also.

Answer (score 1):

Read here: [Mouse Coursor 1](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/stylesc.htm), [Mouse Coursor 2](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("anchor").style.cursor="default";
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in" id="anchor">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a link unclickable like this, using the simple css. This works in mobile devices and desktop also.

```css
 a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Unclickable link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setAttribute` is unreliable if you want the change to be reflected in the document.  Use [`Element.style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536498%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
menuItem.style.cursor='default';
```